# Codeigniter Session library not storing array data

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I run couple of queries in `model` to authenticate if user is valid then store certain data. I am able to store data of one query but unable to save for other. Here is my code in `login controller`

**Controller**

```
if ($user['authenticated']) {

                //Start session
                $this->load->library('session');

                $newdata = array(
                    'user'  => $user['data'],
                    'userPermissions'=>$user['permissions'],
                    'authenticated' => true,
                    'logged_in' => TRUE
                );


                $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

                }
```

I have debugged and successful to see that all the arrays data coming in `user sessions` if i print just above the  `$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);`. Afterwards, I am not sure why `session function` unable to save all the data as I am unable to retrieve the `userPermissions` data in other pages. However, all other data is coming. Here is `session function` code in library

**Library Session**

```
function set_userdata($newdata = array(), $newval = '')
    {
        if (is_string($newdata))
        {
            $newdata = array($newdata => $newval);
        }

        if (count($newdata) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($newdata as $key => $val)
            {
                $this->userdata[$key] = $val;
            }
        }

        $this->sess_write();
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, and only maybe, you're storing so much data in your session. CI don't use native PHP Session but cookie session, which means that if you're storing so much data, your cookie may be so much long and therefore your browser don't return back the whole cookie, just a part. That means, at the end you won't receive in the server all the data.

To solve it, override session core library (you may create your own MY_Session library to avoid messing the core up) with another library which use native PHP session. I use this on my projects: https://bitbucket.org/xperez/core-session-storage-for-codeigniter and work like a charm.